# ng-repeat works wrong AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Get an array from server like this:

[image]

Need to display: info like this

```
<div class="object1">
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
</div>


<div class="object2">
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

Now it work like that:

```
<div class="object1">
    <div class="content"></div>
 </div>
<div class="object1">
    <div class="content"></div>
 </div>
<div class="object2">
    <div class="content"></div>
 </div>
<div class="object2">
    <div class="content"></div>
 </div>
```

There My ng-repeat:

```
<div class="feedback-container">
    <div ng-repeat="feedback in datasfeed | filter:keyword.classname " >
        {{feedback.id}}
        <div  ng-repeat="content in feedback.content" class="feedback-row gt-clear group group-content" >
        <div class="gt-left">
            <div class="ava-round-small"><img src="{{content.user_avatar}}"></div>
        </div>

        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

So how to change code that it will be set How I need?

Comment: Ya Really good question to ask...

Comment: can you share fiddle.. Or your data..

Answer (score 2):

I would do this like that

```
  <div class="feedback-container">
    <div ng-repeat-start="feedback in datasfeed | filter:keyword.classname " >
        {{feedback.id}}  
    </div>
    <div ng-repeat-end ng-repeat="content in feedback.content" class="feedback-row gt-clear group group-content" >
        <div class="gt-left">
            <div class="ava-round-small"><img src="{{content.user_avatar}}"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```